# Different type error when trying to access BLoC data in StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, rxdart

I'm trying to implementing `Bloc` on Flutter and i just learn about this feature and i get error:

**Error:**

> Another exception was thrown: type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Stream'

my server return this structure and i want to get that with `bloc` and `rxDart`, for example:

```
[
    "active"=> 1,
    "name"=> "MY NAME",
    "avatar"=> "http://www.sample.com/avatar.png",
    ...
]
```

my implemented `Repository` class :

```
class Repository {
  final userInformation = InstagramApiProviders();

  Future<UserInfo> userInfo() => userInformation.checkUserLogin();
}
```

`LoginBlock` class

```
class LoginBlock{
  final _repository = Repository();
  final _login_fetcher = PublishSubject<UserInfo>();

  Observable<UserInfo> get login=>_login_fetcher.stream;

  fetchLogin() async{
    UserInfo userInfo = await _repository.userInfo();
    _login_fetcher.sink.add(userInfo);
  }

  dispose(){
    _login_fetcher.close();
  }
}

final bloc = LoginBlock();
```

click on button on view implementation:

```
onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
    if (_checkLoginInstagram()) {
      StreamBuilder(
        stream: bloc.fetchLogin(),
        builder: (context,
            AsyncSnapshot<UserInfo>
            snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            parseResponse(snapshot);
          }
        },
      );
    }
  });
},
```

`parseResponse` method:

```
void parseResponse(AsyncSnapshot<UserInfo> snapshot) {
  debugPrint(snapshot.data.avatar);
}
```

Comment: Please stop appending tag names,  like Flutter, to the titles of your questions, you have the tags at the bottom to indicate the target of the question. Why are you calling bloc.fetchLogin() as the value for stream property of StreamBuilder? Why aren't you exposing the final login_fetcher property and use that in the StreamBuilder's stream property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are providing a Future object instead a stream to `stream` property of your StreamBuilder.

```
//...
StreamBuilder(
        stream: bloc.fetchLogin(), // THIS LINE IS WRONG
```

As your `fetchLogin` is an `async` function by default `async` methods returns always a Future object in your case `Future<void>`. You should replace the wrong line by:

```
 //...
    StreamBuilder(
            stream: bloc.login,
```

And make fetchLogin() call in `onPress` callback and you don't need `setState` calls. I cant get it why you have a setState call there...

Comment: could you help me on this issue?  `https://stackoverflow.com/q/56080076/1830228` thanks in advance