# implementing simple rxDart with Bloc don't get result

Tags: flutter, bloc, rxdart

from this link on my web server as

http://instamaker.ir/api/v1/getPersons

i'm trying to get result and printing `avatar` from that result, unfortunately my implementation with `rxDart` and `Bloc` don't get result from this response and i don't get any error

server response this simplified result:

```
{
  "active": 1,
  "name": "my name",
  "email": " 3 ",
  "loginType": " 3 ",
  "mobile_number": " 3 ",

  ...

  "api_token": "1yK3PvAsBA6r",
  "created_at": "2019-02-12 19:06:34",
  "updated_at": "2019-02-12 19:06:34"
}
```

**`main.dart` file: (click on button to get result from server)**

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: bloc.login,
  builder: (context,
      AsyncSnapshot<UserInfo>
      snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      parseResponse(snapshot);
    }
  },
);
void parseResponse(AsyncSnapshot<UserInfo> snapshot) {
  debugPrint(snapshot.data.avatar);
}
```

**`LoginBlock` class:**

```
class LoginBlock{
  final _repository = Repository();
  final _login_fetcher = PublishSubject<UserInfo>();

  Observable<UserInfo> get login=>_login_fetcher.stream;

  fetchLogin() async{
    UserInfo userInfo = await _repository.userInfo();
    _login_fetcher.sink.add(userInfo);
  }

  dispose(){
    _login_fetcher.close();
  }
}

final bloc = LoginBlock();
```

**`Repository` class:**

```
class Repository {
  final userInformation = InstagramApiProviders();

  Future<UserInfo> userInfo() => userInformation.checkUserLogin();
}
```

**my model:**

```
class UserInfo {
  int _active;
  String _name;
  ...

  UserInfo.fromJsonMap(Map<String, dynamic> map)
      : _active = map["active"],
        _name = map["name"],
        ...

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['active'] = _active;
    data['name'] = _name;
    ...

    return data;
  }

  //GETTERS
}
```

**`BaseUrl` class:**

```
class BaseUrl {
  static const url = 'http://instamaker.ir';
}
```

**and then `InstagramApiProviders` class:**

```
class InstagramApiProviders {
  Client client = Client();

  Future<UserInfo> checkUserLogin() async {
    final response = await client.get(BaseUrl.url+'/api/v1/getPersons');
    print("entered  "+BaseUrl.url+'/api/v1/getPersons');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return UserInfo.fromJsonMap(json.decode(response.body));
    } else
      throw Exception('Failed to load');
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say "don't get result from this response and i don't get any error" is because you can't fetch data from the server or is because you can't see any change in your UI?

Comment: @Marcos Boaventura yes for simple show result i want to use this code `void parseResponse(AsyncSnapshot<UserInfo> snapshot) {
  debugPrint(snapshot.data.avatar);
}`

Comment: Well you need put your StreamBuilder widget inside a widget tree to StreamBuilder **builder method be called I think that is the reason why you can't see any results. I make some tests here and I got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the answer here is part of the test that I make to get this done. I can put my all test here but I think that the problem cause was because as `StreamBuilder` is a widget his `builder` method callback is only called when the widget is in flutter widget tree. As in your sample you're just creating a StreamBuilder the builder method will never be called bacause this widget isn't in widget tree.

As advice first test your code changing only UI layer... do somenthing like:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.assessment), onPressed: () => loginBlock.fetchLogin()),
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<UserInfo>(
        stream: loginBlock.login,
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if (snapshot.hasData){
            parseResponse(snapshot);
            return Text('user: ${snapshot.data.name} ');
          }
          if (snapshot.hasError)
            return Text('${snapshot.error}');
          else return Text('There is no data');
        },
      ),
    );
```

Here we're putting the StreamBuilder in widget tree so the `builder` callback is called and maybe you will see the results. If it fails, please comment that I update my answer with my full test code with this working.

Updating the answer with sources that I made tests.

### Basic model

```
class UserInfo {
  int _active;
  String name;

  UserInfo.fromJsonMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    _active = map["active"];
    name = map["name"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'active' : _active,
    'name' : name,
  };
}
```

### The provider class

```
class InstagramApiProviders {
  Future<UserInfo> checkUserLogin() async {

    UserInfo info;

    try {
      http.Response resp = await http.get("http://instamaker.ir/api/v1/getPersons");
      if (resp.statusCode == 200){
        print('get response');
        print( resp.body );
        info = UserInfo.fromJsonMap(  Map.from(  json.decode(resp.body ) ));
      }
    }
    catch (ex) {
      throw ex;
    }
    print('returning $info');
    return info;
  }
}
```

### Repository

```
class Repository {
  final userInformation = InstagramApiProviders();
  Future<UserInfo> userInfo() => userInformation.checkUserLogin().then((user) => user);
}
```

### BLoC class

```
class LoginBlock{
  final _repository = Repository();
  final _login_fetcher = PublishSubject<UserInfo>();

  Observable<UserInfo> get login=>_login_fetcher.stream;

  fetchLogin() async {
    UserInfo info = await _repository.userInfo();
      _login_fetcher.sink.add(info);
  }

  dispose(){
    _login_fetcher.close();
  }
}
```

### Widget UI

This starts showing `There is no data` message but when you hit appBar button wait a little and then the data is fetched and updates the UI.

```
class WidgetToShowData extends StatelessWidget {

  final LoginBlock bloc = LoginBlock();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.assessment), onPressed: () => loginBlock.fetchLogin()),
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<UserInfo>(
        stream: loginBlock.login,
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if (snapshot.hasData){
            parseResponse(snapshot);
            return Text('user: ${snapshot.data.name} ');
          }
          if (snapshot.hasError)
            return Text('${snapshot.error}');
          else return Text('There is no data');
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void parseResponse(AsyncSnapshot<UserInfo> snapshot) {
    debugPrint(snapshot.data.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i get `There is no data` message. it seems code is correct

Comment: Did you click on appBar icon to fetch data?

Comment: could you please complete your code on post? i get error

Comment: i get `MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.` error

Comment: Well this error is in other part of your source that I didn't see. Try create a simple screen to test only with WidgetToShowData. This test was succesfuly fetching and showing data from your web server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193167/discussion-between-doldurma-and-marcos-boaventura).